# How to install a GUI package from terminal when creating a live cd?

Tags: installation, live-cd

I am in the process of customizing a live ubuntu cd. There are some packages which i would like to install, but they are GUI packages. How to install GUI packages from terminal?

For example : `Adobe Air`.

### Update:

When installing the adobe air application remotely. I get the following error

```
root@user193:~# ./AdobeAIRInstaller.bin

(/tmp/air.FJiIF3/setup:2630): Gtk-WARNING **: cannot open display:
```

Comment: "cannot open display:" add the display to your .bashrc in your home dir. 1st do a "echo DISPLAY$" and add the result as `export DISPLAY=0.0` to .bashrc where 0.0 is changed to what you got from the echo.

Comment: I dont get any output on entering `echo DISPLAY$`.

Comment: You must enter `echo $DISPLAY`. Try running: `DISPLAY=:0 ./AdobeAIRInstaller.bin`. Perhaps the application has a command-line installer too, most programs will show their options using the `--help` options: `./AdobeAIRInstaller.bin --help`

Comment: oops $DISPLAY ofcourse.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Packaged GUI applications should be installable like any other package. For 32-bit Ubuntu, enable the partner repository, refresh the sources list and install Adobe AIR using:

```
sudo apt-get install adobeair
```

`adobeair` is not availabe for the 64-bit version. Neither from the repos, nor from Adobe.

Comment: you must be using 64-bit since adobeair is present in the repos of the 32-bit version

Comment: @Alaukik: I'm indeed using 64-bit, perhaps you can update your answer for that?

Comment: @Lekensteyn pls look at my updates..

Answer (score 1):

you can install them normally via apt-get

```
sudo apt-get install adobeair
```